# Typescript: Base a type on the corresponding Type in a Map

Tags: typescript

I'm using Firestore and I want to associate the paths in my database with the right interface.

Let's say I have 3 possible paths. Here's the type of those paths:

```
type FsPath =
  `badges/${string}` |
  'entities' |
  `entities/${string}`;
```

In the path `entities` and `entities/${string}` I only want to store data with type ServerEntity and in the path `badges/${string}` I only want to store data with type ServerBadge;

```
interface ServerEntity {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface ServerBadge {
  level: number;
  label: string;
}
```

Now let's say I have this function

```
setValue(path: FsPath, value: any) {
  // I want to know how to replace the any with a deduced type from the FsPath of "path"
}
```

What should I write instead of "any" to make sure I can't do the following

```
const badge: ServerBadge = {
  level: 4,
  label: 'Best badge'
};

setValue('entities/qs89sdjdziU', badge); // I want this to raise an TS error
```

How can I create a "Map" (not sure of the term) between my FsPath and my interfaces ServerBadge, ServerEntity?
Then how can I check on this "Map" to type the "value" key in setValue()?

Hope the question is clear enough.

Thanks

EDIT: added ServerBadge and ServerEntity types

EDIT after @captain-yossarian answer:

Is there a way to create a PathMap but with the whole path as keys instead ?

```
type PathMap = {
  'badges': ServerBadge[],
  `badges/${string}`: ServerBadge,
  'entities': ServerEntity[],
  `entities/${string}`: ServerEntity
}
```

I know this won't work because a type key can't be a TS type. So how could I create a Map between 2 types ?

EDIT Added a modified playground with the subcollection issue:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrQG7QKLmGAT2QG8AoZC5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5zK52GqAVxoAjaNwC+pUqEixEKdFCxQACgBsFJHhTD51AlmxBcdyBPgKMjHSdNnR4SNJmgAhOABN+2ysgNY6owgwmJQ3H6aYkHMrLakUqSEAA4oAGJMqnBgABbIALxmAD7IAOQiXvxMpcXIAAYV3hBMAPQAJMQ2JhJ1taUQeHrNNX4ldQN6Q60dXew9teODwM3tnXHdLcmaSEy9o-UT+MvTa8Zzm9srM+tzddxJBKnIWbkAsnDJBb6U5ZXDjEoVB4mgAaMwAbWSUAA9slGA0-idZj0ALoA1xQYH8MF+fpLf4uZQ4QYEHGUSEwuEHfFIm6o9FEqC4SakiFQ2Hww5TVbIi4KXZowkqDQKMkUCkc6mTY48ul8nays70oXQEVIBLSFIoACSTAAanB1MBPAAeAAqAD4vmbkBAAB6QECeJjIADWEAI0Jgz2yOXenwA-D63h9wWaUchghAVJrHigAOIQMAG9SCCDm20OgbO2JnK2FPwACht9sdObqHVAMGgyAyYAkqyrNYA+vM-H4g7qU8aTXWLWY-Ixi5myy6K8Qm1Bayw2+25539Yae33I1Ro9AB5QAJRmLf3GCCEAIPTQkDMJMptMm1Qj7MujIvHIWwvJX2MVQg5AYQ1pxiJ5M-umqgWluJDIIkCCniwyCNPwDJAn8XxkJE64xAALGK-hwNEjClG4zRgDBfw1BI9yQSA0FclYKpMiSSFmNQdC4TkEDqOo0KlJhfACGhABMGqkEwF6AYWeLSisACOTAABwAJxMJ4ABWngAF7AAAqpxtoknuyAtC0yDQq6gnCamECibBwyfpZun6YZxkmQBZmiVyMpSXJCnKWpmnWX8tkGdAMJQKQQA)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you expect from `value`. Please share `ServerBadge` type

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry if it was unclear. I want the type of value to be based on some sort of mapping between a FsPath and an interface. So I want to raise an error if someone is trying to set a badge on the path "entities/smth"

Comment: Why `setValue('entities/qs89sdjdziU', badge);` should cause an error? What the expected value?

Comment: Because I want to. I want to add a security to my code. I don't want my DB to have badges in the Entity collection.

Comment: It is misunderstanding. If you provide `/entities` should `value` be `ServerEntity` ?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to have to set it manually. I want to look it up into a typescript Map or something. I want to bind once all my paths (ie /entities) to the corresponding interfaces (ie ServerEntity) and have TS automatically check if the given value type matches the one bound to the path in parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
interface ServerEntity {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface ServerPlace {
    title: string;
    city: string;
}

interface ServerBadge {
    level: number;
    label: string;
}

type FsPath =
    | 'badges'
    | `badges/${string}`
    | 'entities'
    | `entities/${string}`
    | `entities/${string}/places`
    | `entities/${string}/places/${string}`;


type FsMap = {
    'entities': ServerEntity,
    'badges': ServerBadge
}

type Validate<T> = T extends FsPath ? T : never

type GetPrefix<T extends string> =
    (T extends `${infer Fst}/${infer _}`
        ? Validate<Fst>
        : (T extends `${infer Fst}`
            ? Validate<Fst> : never
        )
    );

type GetValue<T extends FsPath> = GetPrefix<T> extends keyof FsMap ? FsMap[GetPrefix<T>] : never

function setValue<P extends FsPath>(path: P, value: GetValue<P>) { }

const badge: ServerBadge = {
    level: 4,
    label: 'Best badge'
};

const entity: ServerEntity = {
    name: 'hello',
    age: 42
}

setValue('entities/qs89sdjdziU', entity); // ok
setValue('badges', badge); // ok

setValue('entities/qs89sdjdziU', badge); // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrQG7QKLmGAT2QG8AoZC5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5zK52GqAVxoAjaNwC+pUqEixEKdFCxQACgBsFJHhTD51AlmxBcdyBPgKMjHSdNnR4SNJmgAhOABN+2ysgNY6owgwmJQ3H6aYkHMrLakUqSEAA4oAGJMqnBgABbIALxmAD7IAOQiXvxMpcXIAAYV3hBMAPQAJMQ2JhJ1taUQeHrNNX4ldQN6Q60dXew9teODwM3tnXHdLcmaSEy9o-UT+MvTa8Zzm9srM+tzddzSKelMALJwyQW+lP1Lw4xKKrhJgQADRmcqVX4uZTuCEJB4EVLIABqcHUwE82QgAB4ACoAPg+OOQEAAHpAQJ4mMgMllcsgAPzIInBCAqeGIgDiEDAqigEBgwBJuOJZIGlNiZwJhT8AAoiaTyeK6h1QDBoNSWBJVqr1QB9eZ+PyMlFojGQLEZMB4sx+RhykWKqnK4g6qAasAGw1e42o9GYi0sAkstleigASjMYfuj2QXLAJsE2PloopVJp2RyUtj3N5-MFuIJCrFVIA1hACAB7GAa17vRkZWsAbTjuYFQvxAF1kMHoNIYIIQAg9BWQMxuQnsaoHcWNbTMzLkhnGKpgcgMKjE4w4xOsao8WGSMhEggRyxkI1+H9XFAPE0PmRIqyIDEACygyJwaKMUpuZpgc8QjUEj3CeIBnochBXtCUCApY95mNQdDfjkz7qBWpTvrwl7IC+ABMcKkEw44bhAMrfJMxwtAAjkwAAcACcTCeAAVp4ABewAAKoYcSgwEFGyAtC0yAViWhHEeoiZkRewyrjJAlCSJYnifGJFkRBlE0QxTGsRx3FyRCCnCdAUAVlApBAA)

`PathMap` is just a dictionary, nothing special.

`GetValue` splits the path into two parts ${first part}/${second part}. Then, it checks whether `first part` is a key of dictionary or not. If it is - get value by key, otherwise - return never.

You can find more interesting examples regarding function arguments validation in my [article](https://catchts.com/validators)

Comment: Oh crap. It won't work for subcollections though. Path can be entities/ID_HERE/places/ID_HERE for instance. But only ServerPlace should be a valid type for this path.

Comment: @Maslow please provide more information into the question with appropriate examples of expected and unexpected behavior

Comment: Really nice. Thx! I've updated the issue with an updated playground with the subcollection issue. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Do you have any other requirements? I mean, is there any pattern for allowed paths?

Comment: Well there can be subcollections in subcollections but the max is coll1/blabla/coll2/blibli/coll3/bloblo. Then it should be fine I think. Thx again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237133/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-maslow).